# Undefined index error when getting results using the field name in oracle pdo connection

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

```
<?php 
include ("pdo_mysql_connect.php");  
// include ("pdo_oracle_connect.php");  
$query="select city ,state  from student";
$dataf = $pdoc->query($query);  
for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) {
$resultf = $dataf->fetch(); 
echo ".- ".$resultf['city'] . " - " . $resultf['state'] . "<br />";
echo $resultf[0] . " | " . $resultf[1] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

using the above code with pdo mysql connection I get the results as expected
.- London - England
London | England
.- Hyderabad - Andhra Pradesh
Hyderabad | Andhra Pradesh
.- North York - Ontario
North York | Ontario

but whith the oracle pdo connection there is an Undefined index error when the reference is with the field name.
Notice: Undefined index: city in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: state in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 8
While the numeric reference works.
.- -
London | England
... etc
How can I get the results using the field name in oracle connection? or I have stumbled into a bug? do I need to provide additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle returns field names as uppercase by default so you need to use uppercase indexes like so:

```
echo ".- ".$resultf['CITY'] . " - " . $resultf['STATE'] . "<br />";
```

Comment: But the output of print_r($resultf) is Array ( [city] => London [state] => England ) ...etc  which means key is 'city'

Comment: Are you sure you checked it against Oracle and not MySQL? Unless you've configured PDO to [return always in lowercase](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) then PDO will return indexes in uppercase as you haven't aliased the fields in your query.

Comment: Yes, the capital case for field names solved it. Thanks to all for your answers.

Comment: an addition, as I see even aliases need to be in upper case.