# Trying to get property of non-object using OCI connection

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I'm new in PHP with OCI connection. I want to retrieve some data from database and insert it into a table form. But it keep show an error

> Trying to get property 'attribute' of non-object

I have try to use oci_fetch object / oci_fetch_array, but it still the same. I also have followed some tutorial but it doesn't help.

This is for my mini project for this semester.

Here my source code:

```
$sql="SELECT borrow.book_id, book_title, borrow.stud_id, stud_name, book_bdate, return_date, due_date
      FROM book
      JOIN borrow
      ON  book.book_id = borrow.book_id
      JOIN student
      ON borrow.stud_id = student.stud_id
      where borrow.stud_id = '$stud_id'
      ORDER BY 5 DESC ";

$query=oci_parse($link,$sql) or die ("error here!");
oci_execute($query); 

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
?>    
    <td><?php echo $row->stud_id; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row->book_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->book_title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->book_bdate; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row->due_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->return_date; ?></td>

    <td>
<center><a href='return-book.php?book_id=<?php echo $row->book_id; ?>'>Update</a></center>
</td>

<tr>

<?php
}
}


oci_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index error when getting results using the field name in oracle pdo connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041150/undefined-index-error-when-getting-results-using-the-field-name-in-oracle-pdo-co)

Comment: I'm so sorry. My bad. And thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle returns field names as uppercase by default so you need to use uppercase indexes like so:

[Here the solution where I got.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041150/undefined-index-error-when-getting-results-using-the-field-name-in-oracle-pdo-co)

Btw thank you everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Your while loop You are fetching data as `array`:

> oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC) // return associated array

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
?>    
    <td><?php echo $row['stud_id']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['book_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['book_bdate']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['due_date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['return_date']; ?></td>

    <td>
<center><a href='return-book.php?book_id=<?php echo $row['book_id']; ?>'>Update</a></center>
</td>

<tr>

<?php
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It said that "Notice: Undefined index: stud_id in....."

Comment: Then check your query or print `$row` see whats coming on that array

Comment: I hv print the $row and the output is exact as what in the db.

Comment: can you also print the output or dummy data same like your output?

Comment: check [oci-fetch-array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) function for more information. Examples.

Comment: yes I also print the output or dummy data. And it worked. But this doesn't work